# Не работает ползунок

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я делаю генератор паролей, при увеличении ползунка генерируемый пароль тоже должен увеличиваться, но это не работает

```js
function updatePasswordLength(length) {
  document.getElementById("passwordLengthValue").textContent = length;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adaptive.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input class="output" type="text" id="passwordInput" readonly>

  <div class="settings">
    <button onclick="generatePassword()" class="btn1" id="js-btn2">gen</button>
    <button class="btn2" id="js-btn1">copy</button>
  </div>

  <input type="range" id="passwordLengthInput" min="6" max="20" step="1" value="10" oninput="updatePasswordLength(this.value)">
  <span id="passwordLengthValue">10</span>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="pasword.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Если запустить тут твой пример - циферки меняются, если двигать ползунок... Но самой функции `generatePassword` в примере нет...

Comment: @ksa она у него в предыдущем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1532390)...